# If $x^3-9x^2+21x-3=0$ then evaluate $x(3-x)^2$

Tags: polynomials, cubics

If $x^3-9x^2+21x-3=0$ then evaluate $x(3-x)^2$.

I managed to write the equation as  $(x-3)^3-6(x-3)+6=0$ but could not proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

(First off, I don't see *the* trick, either, so the following just tackles it the hard way.)

The systematic approach for this would be to let $x (x - 3)^2 = a$, then note that polynomials

$$P(x) = x^3-9x^2+21x-3$$
$$Q(x) = x^3-6x^2+9x-a$$

must have a common root by the given condition and the definition of $a$. This is equivalent to their [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) being $0$, which (after not so pretty calculations, deferred to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant(x%5E3+%E2%88%929x%5E2+%2B21x%E2%88%923,+x(x-3)%5E2+-+a))) reduces to:

$$-a^3+18 a^2-108 a+108 = 0$$

The latter cubic can be solved by [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) for example, with the roots being:

$$a_1 = 6 - 3 \; \sqrt[3]{4}$$

$$a_{2,3} = 6+ 3\;\frac{1 \pm i \sqrt{3}}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$$

The real root $a_1$ is the answer if the question is restricted to real values, all $3$ roots are possible answers in complex numbers.

Comment: Very interesting solution. But this question in itself - apparently - as you say it , has no hidden *trick* and does not deserve the [+3] upvotes at all (friends of the OP ?).

Answer (score 2):

By brute force, you find that the only real solution to 
$ x^3-9x^2+21x-3=0 $ 
is $x = 3-2^{1/3}-2^{2/3}$ and hence

$$
x(3-x)^2 = 3 (2-2^{2/3})
$$

However, I wonder what is the deeper meaning behind this question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm missing "the trick" that would make this easy but you now have a depressed cubic in $y = x-3$:

$$y^3 - 6y + 6 = 0.$$

You can use [Vieta's substitution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasSubstitution.html) to solve for the real root, back out $x$, and then calculate $x(3-x)^2$.